# Problem fixing my corrupted USB drive on OS X

Tags: macos, hard-drive, usb, permission

I followed your tutorial [How do I fix a corrupted USB drive on OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220711/how-do-i-fix-a-corrupted-usb-drive-on-os-x)
and got the final message:

> dd: /dev/disk2: Permission denied

Then I tried it with a *sudo command* and got the message:

> dd: /dev/disk2: Resource busy

Do you have an idea how I can successfully fix my corrupted USB drive?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to unmount the disk first. Before you can write to it using `dd`Here the command you need to run to unmount the disk:

```
sudo diskutil unmount /dev/disk2
```

Comment: Correct so +1, to be more complete: if the disk would've had multiple volumes using `unmountDisk` would be advised.

Comment: @Montmons To my knowledge there is no unmountDisk command, only unmount and unmountVolume. unmount should unmount the disk and all its volumes. But I could also be incorrect